# .net webservice json modification help object wihing obect

Tags: javascript, .net, json, web-services

Hello guys i have been able to figure out how to simple send a class from a .net webservice.

here is my class

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class TestClass

    Public Class Person

        Public Class Names
            'Public Property Firsname As String
            Public Property ID As Integer
            Public Property LastName As String
            Shared Property FirstName As String

        End Class
    End Class
End Class
```

here is how im using it in my code,

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function PersonList(ID As Integer) As List(Of Person.Names)
        'Dim p As New Person With {.ID = ID, .FirstName = "Kenneth"}
        Try




            Dim ListPerson As New List(Of Person.Names)



            For startNumber = 1 To 4
                Dim Per As New Person.Names

                Per.ID = startNumber
                ListPerson.Add(Per)
            Next

            Return ListPerson



        Catch ex As Exception

            Dim Per As New Person.Names

            Per.ID = ex.Message

            Dim ListPerson As New List(Of Person.Names)

            ListPerson.Add(Per)



        End Try

    End Function
```

This works well when i return JSON but now i like to push a little further.
I would like to have lists withing lists. Is this possible.

look at this image.[image]

i would like to return an array below id not just a value for id.
How would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

the trick here is serializing the XML and i need it to make one of my class members list of string that accomplished exactly what i wanted to do.
Thanks everyone